How to block safari on recovery mode? Macbook M2
My son has a porn addiction issue, and I have set up a dns profile which he cannot change as he is not the administrator on the MacOS. However, he has discovered in recovery mode a built in browser which anyone can use without the need for any password. This browser circumvents any dns configurations.
I cannot set up dns router level since the router can be reset with a button on the back of the router and be reconfigured. And he can use the Macbook outside of the home as well.
Does anyone know how can I set up a password or disable the safari on recovery mode?

Welcome to Ask Different. If your son's Mac has the Apple T2 Security Chip (see https://support.apple.com/103265 for a list of Mac computers with the T2 Security Chip), you can set a firmware password so that the Mac asks for it when starting up from macOS Recovery, see https://support.apple.com/102384 for details. Could you check it out and report back?

for T2 yes but for M2 this solution doesn't work. For example, the '''firmwarepasswd -setpasswd''' will return that this feature is not available

You are right, the links I posted apply to Intel Macs only. According to https://support.apple.com/102384, "[f]or the equivalent level of security on a Mac with Apple silicon, simply turn on FileVault" and, according to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253764365?answerId=257057522022&sortBy=rank#257057522022, "FileVault [prevents users] who don't know the admin account password from using the recovery utilities", so FileVault may help. If you want to give it a try and turn it on, see this article: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/protect-data-on-your-mac-with-filevault-mh11785/mac.

I can’t think of a way to prevent this Mac if it has internet from booting to internet recovery or local recovery to avoid the blocks you’ve planned.
Apple’s security perimeter is to prevent Apple Silicon Mac’s from being re-activated if locked and prevent access to encrypted contents.
They aren’t designed to lock anyone in possession of a Mac out of the internet with safari for recovery OS operations on “locked down” hardware.
You’ll likely have to enhance your network filtering at home or substitute older hardware that allows a firmware lock. Ubiquity has great routers which can be well secured should someone attempt to reset one. You could only allow OS that have the correct network key to connect to the internet.
DNS blocks are able to add some resistance, but a motivated person can get around them in most cases. Good luck with managing this parenting dilemma. Your most effective measures will be non technical and based on your child’s age, of limited success as they gain access to friends and other devices outside your control.
